# Lightning mainnet peer list?

Tags: lightning-network, core-lightning, ln-topology

I just set up c-lightning on mainnet and I'd like to open a channel but I can't find a list of node ids and ip addresses. Does anyone know where I can find this?

Answer (score 6):

Here's a site with all the nodes on mainnet
https://1ml.com

Answer (score 4):

I am developer of https://lightblock.me It's a tool which lets you search for nodes which you wish to connect to, take the URI of the node you want to connect and use it with "connect" command.

Answer (score -1):

Blockstream:
`02f6725f9c1c40333b67faea92fd211c183050f28df32cac3f9d69685fe9665432@104.198.32.198`

Stampery:
`02c0ac82c33971de096d87ce5ed9b022c2de678f08002dc37fdb1b6886d12234b5@13.80.67.162`

Answer (score -1):

From [LN specifications:](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc/blob/master/08-transport.md)

> First, before any actual data transfer, both nodes participate in an
>   authenticated key agreement handshake...

and then inside the **Authenticated Key Agreement Handshake**:

> the initiator must know the identity public key of the responder...